# WaitForSingleObject() vs RegisterWaitForSingleObject()?

Tags: windows, winapi, visual-c++

What is the advantage/disadvantage over using `RegisterWaitForSingleObject()` instead of `WaitForSingleObject()`?

The reason that I know:

1. `RegisterWaitForSingleObject()` uses the thread pool already available in OS
2. In case of the use of `WaitForSingleObject()`, an own thread should be polling for the event.

the only difference is Polling vs. Automatic Event? or Is there any considerable performance advantage between these?

Comment: I would expect slightly faster response to signaled objects due to the fact that API response is the callback on the thread already being executed rather than scheduling original caller thread for execution. Also, multiple callbacks can be called with out context switches. Makes sense when multiple frequent event handling is in question.

Comment: @InnovWelt, I assume you meant 'pooling' rather than 'polling' (which otherwise would mean you periodically 'poll' for something, e.g check event status in a loop).

Comment: @avo: I meant 'polling' when using `WaitForSingleObject()`. i.e., the particular event is polled by calling `WaitForSingleObject()` everytime.

Comment: @InnovWelt, AFAIK [polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) assumes checking for something periodically with high frequency (*busy waiting* comes into my mind). This would be the case if you called `WaitForSingleObject` in a tight loop, with a fairly small `timeout` parameter. Otherwise, `WaitForSingleObject` remains to be a quite efficient way to wait for an event.

Comment: @avo: yes, I agree. currently, I am using `WaitForSingleObject` with continuous polling for the event occurrence. In this way, it is easy to predict the thread execution behaviour and there is no need to think about complex asynchronous scenarios. So, I am sticking with this method. thanks for the inputs!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's pretty straight-forward, WaitForSingleObject() blocks a thread.  It is consuming a megabyte of virtual memory and not doing anything useful with it while it is blocked.  It won't wake up and resume doing useful stuff until the handle is signaled.

RegisterWaitForSingleObject() does *not* block a thread.  The thread can continue doing useful work.  When the handle is signaled, Windows grabs a thread-pool thread to run the code you specified as the callback.  The same code you would have programmed after a WFSO call.  There is still a thread involved with getting that callback to run, the *wait thread*, but it can handle many RWFSO requests.

So the big advantage is that your program can use a lot less threads while still handling many service requests.  A disadvantage is that it can take a bit longer for the completion code to start running.  And it is harder to program correctly since that code runs on another thread.  Also note that you don't need RWFSO when you already use overlapped I/O.

Comment: Yes. In my scenario, I have only one explicit task to be carried out and I don't want to handle the asynchronous threads & so on. So, I am creating a thread of my own and restricting the execution to be only carried out by this particular thread. It made the solution quicker to implement! Thanks for clarifying about RWFSO.

Comment: @InnovWelt - it's courteous to accept answers that you're happy with.

Comment: @Hans Passant: Where does the memory consumption of WaitForSingleObject come from? Is it documented somewhere? The only thing I found is that it may fail if there is not enough memory left. Does it come frome some synchronization object being created?

Comment: @ba__friend I think the "megabyte of virtual memory" is occupied by the thread's stack. The default size of a thread stack in Windows is 1 MB, according to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686774.aspx

Answer (score 3):

They serve two different code models. In case with `RegisterWaitForSingleObject` you'll get an asynchronous notification callback on a random thread from the thread pool managed by the OS. If you can structure your code like this, it might be more efficient. On the other hand, `WaitForSingleObject` is a synchronous wait call blocking (an thus 'occupying') the calling thread. In most cases, such code is easier to write and would probably be less error-prone to various dead-lock and race conditions.